# Expecting code to raise a throwable spring JUnit

Tags: spring-boot, unit-testing, junit

I am using Java unit tests. When we give the parameters correctly, the unit test should work without any errors (green). But I am getting such an error. Java version 1.8

```
Expecting code to raise a throwable.
```

**TicTacToeService**

```
public class TicTacToeService {

    public void play(int x, int y) {
        if(x<0)
            throw  new IllegalArgumentException("x cannot be negative");

        if (y < 0)
            throw  new IllegalArgumentException("y cannot be negative");

        if (x > 2)
            throw  new IllegalArgumentException("x cannot be greater than 2");

        if (y > 2)
            throw  new IllegalArgumentException("y cannot be greater than 2");
    }

}
```

**TicTacToeTest**

```
public class TicTacToeTest {

    private TicTacToeService ticTacToeService = new TicTacToeService();

    @Test
    public void givenXIsNegativeExpectException(){
        int x = -1;
        int y = 1;

        Assertions.assertThatThrownBy(() -> ticTacToeService.play(x, y))
                .isInstanceOf(IllegalArgumentException.class)
                .hasMessage("X cannot be negative");
    }

    @Test
    public void givenYIsNegativeExpectException(){
        int x = 1;
        int y = -1;

        Assertions.assertThatThrownBy(() -> ticTacToeService.play(x, y))
                .isInstanceOf(IllegalArgumentException.class)
                .hasMessage("y cannot be negative");
    }

}
```

**dependencies**

```
dependencies {
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web'
    implementation("org.modelmapper:modelmapper:2.3.7")
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-validation'
    testCompile group: 'junit', name: 'junit', version: '4.4'
    implementation 'org.liquibase:liquibase-core'
    compileOnly 'org.projectlombok:lombok'
    runtimeOnly 'mysql:mysql-connector-java'
    annotationProcessor 'org.projectlombok:lombok'
    testImplementation('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test') {
        exclude group: 'org.junit.vintage', module: 'junit-vintage-engine'
    }
    testCompile group: 'org.assertj', name: 'assertj-core', version: '3.6.1'
    testCompile group: 'org.junit.jupiter', name: 'junit-jupiter-api', version: '5.7.0'
}
```

[image: error pic]

What is the problem? please help me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect that you are using `assertThatThrownBy` but in reality, you want to use `assertThrows`. You can check this [link](https://www.baeldung.com/junit-assert-exception) for example.

Answer (score 0):

I can declare my own custom runtime exception write it as below

service class

```java
@Service
public class TicTacToeService {

    public void play(int x, int y) {
        if (x < 0)
            throw new XNegativeException("x cannot be negative");

        if (y < 0)
            throw new YNegativeException("y cannot be negative");

        if (x > 2)
            throw new XLimitException("x cannot be greater than 2");

        if (y > 2)
            throw new YLimitException("y cannot be greater than 2");
    }

    static class XNegativeException extends RuntimeException{
        public XNegativeException(String message) {
            super(message);
        }
    }

    static class YNegativeException extends RuntimeException{
        public YNegativeException(String message) {
            super(message);
        }
    }

    static class XLimitException extends RuntimeException{
        public XLimitException(String message) {
            super(message);
        }
    }

    static class YLimitException extends RuntimeException{
        public YLimitException(String message) {
            super(message);
        }
    }

}
```

Test File

```java
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Assertions;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;

class TicTacToeServiceTest {
    private final TicTacToeService ticTacToeService = new TicTacToeService();

    @Test
    void testXIsNegative() {
        Assertions.assertThrows(TicTacToeService.XNegativeException.class,
                () -> ticTacToeService.play(-1, 0));
    }

    @Test
    void testYIsNegative() {
        Assertions.assertThrows(TicTacToeService.YNegativeException.class,
                () -> ticTacToeService.play(0, -898));
    }


    @Test
    void testXLimitReached() {
        Assertions.assertThrows(TicTacToeService.XLimitException.class,
                () -> ticTacToeService.play(3, 0));
    }


    @Test
    void testYLimitReached() {
        Assertions.assertThrows(TicTacToeService.YLimitException.class,
                () -> ticTacToeService.play(0, 3));
    }
}
```